# How do I auto add new lines and indent to a backtick in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext3, auto-indent

Using sublime text. Similar to how when you add a new bracket { and hit enter, it creates a new indented block like so (the .... are spaces):

```
{
....
}
```

I would like the same thing to happen when I use backticks (since I'm using stlyed-components).

So when I input `+enter, I would get:

```
`
....
`
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a new keybinding for <kbd>Enter</kbd>, with specific conditions. Open **`Preferences → Key Bindings`** and add the following to the right side:

```json
    { "keys": ["enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Add Line in Braces.sublime-macro"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "`$", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^`", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
```

This will only run if you have the `"auto_indent"` setting on, the selection is empty, and the characters immediately before and after the cursor are backticks.